# jQuery UI draggable is not a function Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Ok, I keep getting an error message and am unable to drag any of the divs...

Error message is as follows:

> Uncaught exception: TypeError:
>   '$(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").draggable' is not a
>   function Error thrown at line 343, column 4 in ($)
>   in http://developers.dream-portal.net/test/index.php:
>       $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").draggable({ called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 2, column 33900 in (t) in
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:
>       if(a[u].apply(t[0],t[1])===!1&&e.stopOnFalse) called from line 2, column 34244 in () in
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:
>       (function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))
>   called from line 2, column 22488 in (e) in
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js:
>       return v.ready.promise().done(e),this called from line 276, column 3 in startPolaroids() in
>   http://developers.dream-portal.net/test/index.php:
>       jQuery(document).ready(function($){ called from line 1322, column 5 in () in
>   http://developers.dream-portal.net/test/Themes/default/scripts/script.js?fin20:
>       aOnloadEventsi;

I am using an external js file that gets loaded in the head of the webpage with the following function:

```
var aOnloadEvents = new Array();
function addLoadEvent(fNewOnload)
{
    // If there's no event set, just set this one
    if (typeof(fNewOnload) == 'function' && (!('onload' in window) || typeof(window.onload) != 'function'))
        window.onload = fNewOnload;

    // If there's just one event, setup the array.
    else if (aOnloadEvents.length == 0)
    {
        aOnloadEvents[0] = window.onload;
        aOnloadEvents[1] = fNewOnload;
        window.onload = function() {
            for (var i = 0, n = aOnloadEvents.length; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (typeof(aOnloadEvents[i]) == 'function')
                    aOnloadEvents[i]();
                else if (typeof(aOnloadEvents[i]) == 'string')
                    eval(aOnloadEvents[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // This isn't the first event function, add it to the list.
    else
        aOnloadEvents[aOnloadEvents.length] = fNewOnload;
}
```

And in the body of the webpage (which is all I can access from the script that runs it), I have the following code written in PHP (so please excuse the escaping of quotations):

```
// Only want to load up jQuery 1 time here!
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = true;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

if(!jQuery.ui)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = true;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

function randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(minVal, maxVal)
{
    var randVal = minVal + (Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal + 1));
    return Math.round(randVal);
}

function startPolaroids()
{
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        // Set up default values.
        var offsetStartX = 0;
        var offsetEndX = $(document).width() - $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").width();
        var offsetStartY = 0;
        var offsetEndY = $(document).height() - $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").height();
        var objContain = 'document';
            var objEle = document.getElementById("placeholder");
            if (objEle)
            {

                var getObjOffset = $("#placeholder").position();

                offsetStartX = getObjOffset.left;
                offsetEndX = (offsetStartX + $("#placeholder").outerWidth(true)) - $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").width();
                offsetStartY = getObjOffset.top;
                offsetEndY = (offsetStartY + $("#placeholder").outerHeight(true)) - $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").height();

                if (offsetEndY < offsetStartY)
                    offsetEndY = offsetStartY + 1;

                if (offsetEndX < offsetStartX)
                    offsetEndX = offsetStartX + 1;
                objContain = '#placeholder';
            }

        // When everything has loaded, place all polaroids on a random position relative to document or element id!
        $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").each(function (i) {
            var tempVal = Math.round(Math.random());
            if(tempVal == 1) {
                var rotDegrees = randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(330, 360); // rotate left
            } else {
                var rotDegrees = randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(0, 30); // rotate right
            }

            var cssObj = { 'left' : randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(offsetStartX, offsetEndX),
                'top' : randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(offsetStartY, offsetEndY),
                msTransform: 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // IE 9
                '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)',  // Firefox
                '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)',  // Safari & Chrome
                '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // Opera
                'transform' : 'rotate\('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)' }; // added in case CSS3 is standard
            $(this).css(cssObj);
        });

        // Set the Z-Index (used to display images on top while dragging)
        var zindexnr = 1;

        // boolean to check if the user is dragging
        var dragging = false;

        // Show the polaroid on top when clicked on
        $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").mouseup(function(e){
            if(!dragging) {
                // Bring polaroid to the foreground
                zindexnr++;
                var cssObj = { 'z-index' : zindexnr,
                'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',           // added in case CSS3 is standard
                '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',   // Chrome and Safari
                msTransform: 'rotate(0deg)', // IE 9
                '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',      // Firefox
                '-o-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)' };      // Opera
                $(this).css(cssObj);
            }
        });

        // Make the polaroid draggable & display a shadow when dragging
        $(".polaroidpolaroid_attachments_mod_25").draggable({
            cursor: 'pointer',
            containment: objContain,
            start: function(event, ui) {
                dragging = true;
                zindexnr++;
                var cssObj = { 'box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // added in case CSS3 is standard
                    '-ms-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // IE 9
                    '-o-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px',  // Opera
                    '-moz-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // firefox 3.5 - 4.0
                    '-webkit-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Chrome & Safari
                    'margin-left' : '-10px',
                    'margin-top' : '-10px',
                    'z-index' : zindexnr };
                $(this).css(cssObj);
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var tempVal = Math.round(Math.random());
                if(tempVal == 1) {
                    var rotDegrees = randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(330, 360); // rotate left
                } else {
                    var rotDegrees = randomNum_polaroid_attachments_mod_25(0, 30); // rotate right
                }
                var cssObj = { 'box-shadow' : '', // added in case CSS3 is standard
                    '-ms-box-shadow' : '', // IE 9
                    '-o-box-shadow' : '',  // Opera
                    '-moz-box-shadow' : '', // firefox 3.5 - 4.0
                    '-webkit-box-shadow' : '', // Chrome & Safari
                    'transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // added in case CSS3 is standard
                    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // Chrome & Safari
                    msTransform: 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // IE 9
                    '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)',  // Firefox
                    '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees + 'deg)', // Opera
                    'margin-left' : '0px',
                    'margin-top' : '0px' };
                $(this).css(cssObj);
                dragging = false;
            }
        });
    })
}
        // Calling SMF js function, defined in script.js, here.
        addLoadEvent(startPolaroids);
```

I am unable the drag the divs, and they DO EXIST in the HTML.  Am getting that error above, so, trying to pinpoint the exact problem here, could use another pair of eyes on this.

Here is a link to the actual page also, if it would help:  http://developers.dream-portal.net/test/index.php

Thanks guys :)

So, if I change this:

```
// Only want to load up jQuery 1 time here!
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = true;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

if(!jQuery.ui)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = true;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}
```

To this:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   var uiScript = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   uiScript.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = false;
   uiScript.async = false;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   uiScript.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];

   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(uiScript, s);
}
```

It than WORKS, which seems good and all, but the code does NOT put the jQuery UI in, if jQuery exists and jQuery UI doesn't on the page already.  And how would I do that exactly?  Cause other software could be manipulating the page also, and adding jQuery to the pages.  How should I code this?  Thinking we can't use oScripts[0] to be inserted before that element... cause we really won't know where the jQuery is being called from, just that it exists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your jQuery UI is not loaded. Your script:

```
if(!jQuery.ui)
{
   // bla bla
}
```

Is causing error, since the jQuery is not defined. I think that you should wait for the jQuery to be fully loaded first then continue to the next function to check availability of jQuery UI. You need to use Synhronous execution of your script:

```
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = false; // CHANGES
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}
```

Comment: Have made these changes, but now I'm getting undefined variable:  jQuery.  How do you suggest that I wait for the jQuery to be loaded first?

Comment: Perhaps I should use a `while loop` of some sort on this?  Any ideas?

Comment: @SolomonClosson I opened again your page URL above and I found that it was fixed and I did not see any errors. I even used the drag function. Have you managed the problem?

Comment: Ok, In my question, I have updated it at the bottom with the changes I made, however, this needs more work so as to not load multiple instances of the jQuery UI.

Comment: And also, the problem with this approach is that if jQuery is loaded, than it won't bother to load the jQuery UI, cause it will think it's loaded.  I still need to check if the jQuery UI is loaded if jQuery is loaded...  So, that could go into an else statement no problem... but the jQuery UI needs to be loaded after jQuery, so I couldn't use `oScripts[0]` to `insertBefore` could I?

Comment: Argg, actually doesn't need to check for multiple instances of jQuery UI if jQuery is undefined...  DUH!  Don't know why I didn't see that.  Just needs to check for multiple instances of jQuery UI IF jQuery IS already defined! and if so, don't add it again.  But if not, than it will need to be added (But could we use oScripts[0] for this still?)

Comment: And also, thanks for pointing me in the right place and getting me started... :)  +1

Comment: Marking this as my answer, and I resolved the issue for now.  Quite frankly, something about it doesn't seem right.  Not sure what `async` actually does, but I set both jQuery and jQuery UI scripts to false on this to be sure I suppose...  Thanks :)

Comment: Well sure, you're welcome. Glad that I could help you with this :)

Answer (score 1):

**Sequence** is very important , you need to first load/import JQuery and then only Jquery UI. as below :
       `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`